# DMARC report cconfusion

Tags: email, spf, spoofing, dmarc

Having trouble interpreting a dmarc report (from Google). Our dmarc policy is currently set to quarantine.

> 

```
  <record>
       <row>
           <source_ip>NOT.OUR.IP.ADDRESS</source_ip>
           <count>1</count>
           <policy_evaluated>
               <disposition>none</disposition>
               <dkim>pass</dkim>
               <spf>fail</spf>
           </policy_evaluated>
       </row>
       <identifiers>
           <header_from>OUR.DOMAIN</header_from>
       </identifiers>
       <auth_results>
           <dkim>
               <domain>OTHER.DOMAIN</domain>
               <result>pass</result>
               <selector>default</selector>
           </dkim>
           <dkim>
               <domain>OUR.DOMAIN</domain>
               <result>pass</result>
               <selector>OUR.SELECTOR</selector>
           </dkim>
           <spf>
               <domain>OTHER.DOMAIN</domain>
               <result>pass</result>
           </spf>
       </auth_results>
  </record>
```

The OTHER.DOMAIN has an spf record.

I'm not sure why the auth_results all show pass but spf ultimately fails.  Is this because there was a dkim check for our domain but no spf check?

Does anyone know what happened here?  Has our domain been spoofed by OTHER.DOMAIN? The IP address matches OTHER.DOMAIN.

thanks

j

Comment: Ahh! Could this occur if we sent an email to EMAIL@OTHER.DOMAIN and there was some forwarding occurring from there?  I checked and emails were sent to addresses at that domain.  If this is the case and we enable a reject policy would these forwardings fail?

Answer (score 0):

`record//row//auth_results` includes the results of the SPF and checks. A `pass` here is necessary but not sufficient for your DMARC policy to pass.

What is checked next is if the domains are *aligned* (see [RFC 7489 Section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489#section-3.1) for details). Since the SPF check is referring to OTHER.DOMAIN, `record//row//policy_evaluated//spf`, you get a `fail` here. This is unlike DKIM for which a result for OUR.DOMAIN exists. In DMARC terms, this identifier is *aligned*, so `record//row//policy_evaluated//dkim` is `pass`.

Note that it is [sufficient for either one to pass](https://serverfault.com/a/882365). This means, there is no reason to reject/quarantine the 1 message coming from this source IP.